# Handle Postgres server gracefully in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

At the moment, when I start my postgres server (after a configuration change, e.g.), my rails app goes bonkers with FATAL errors while the server is restarting.

Instead of throwing an error, i'd like my rails app to wait for 5 seconds for the box to come back up. Is there a way to make that happen?

I'm using Rails 4.1 and Postgres 9.3.

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the thrown error in the application controller?

Comment: Paul, it is. But I want my app to wait for the db to come back up. Sorry, I realise that the question was ambiguous about this. Edited.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't think your question was ambiguous. But I was posing that suggestion because I'm thinking it may be a better alternative than to cause a long wait time while the database boots up. I'm personally uncertain whether what you're thinking is possible; not without causing the current thread to wait, which may be problematic.

Comment: @CoffeeBite You could catch the error in your controller and send a 302 redirect back to the same page after sleeping a couple of seconds.  If the DB is up, all is well.  If not, it will try again.

Comment: in case of error you should be able to set the delayed actio for the specific request in a controller

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom that's a clever idea. Problem with that is, let's say a request makes 2 non-idempotent DB writes. The server goes down after the first write (Of course, I can solve this by wrapping all requests inside a transaction, but often it is not desired).

Comment: @PaulRichter We usually do restarts when traffic is low. So a bunch of people waiting is really not an issue. The DB usually restarts in under 5 seconds.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ How would that work exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added pgbouncer between my postgresql server and the app. pgbouncer allows me to pause connections while I restart the postgresql server and resume the connections when the server comes back up.